# Multiple Select Unselect And Disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I Have 2 Multiple Select Field On My Code

I Want Make If All Selected Then Other Option Will Be Unselect And Disabled And Similarly If Other Any Field Selected Then All Option Will Unselect And Disabled

My Code Is

```
<select multiple name="device[]" id="device" class="form-control" >
  <option value=\'ALL\' selected="selected">ALL</option>
  <option value=\'Android\'>Android</option>
  <option value=\'iPod\'>iPod</option>
  <option value=\'iPad\'>iPad</option>
  <option value=\'Java\'>Java</option>
  <option value=\'Windows\'>Windows</option>
  <option value=\'Linux\'>Linux</option>
  <option value=\'Mac\'>Mac</option>
</select>
```

And

```
<select multiple name="country[]" id="device" class="form-control" >
  <option value=\'ALL\' selected="selected">ALL</option>
  <option value=\'BD\'>Bangladesh</option>
  <option value=\'IN\'>India</option>
  <option value=\'ID\'>Indonesia</option>
  <option value=\'NG\'>Naigeria</option>
  <option value=\'PK\'>Pakistan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Alex,Please try the latest updated code of mine.It is working fine for me.Please let me know if you have still issues in that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

How about adding an extra button to reset the menus ?
Please [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a0Ldt8f/)

OLD:

If you are not holding ctrl key then other options will be deselected automatically

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#device, #country').on('change', function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedVal.length; i++) {
      if (selectedVal[i] === 'ALL') {
        // $("#device > option").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(this).find('option').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).find('option[value=ALL]').removeAttr('disabled');
      } else {
        $(this).find('option[value=ALL]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name="device[]" id="device" class="form-control">
  <option value='ALL'>ALL</option>
  <option value='Android'>Android</option>
  <option value='iPod'>iPod</option>
  <option value='iPad'>iPad</option>
  <option value='Java'>Java</option>
  <option value='Windows'>Windows</option>
  <option value='Linux'>Linux</option>
  <option value='Mac'>Mac</option>
</select>

<select multiple name="country[]" id="country" class="form-control">
  <option value='ALL'>ALL</option>
  <option value='BD'>Bangladesh</option>
  <option value='IN'>India</option>
  <option value='ID'>Indonesia</option>
  <option value='NG'>Naigeria</option>
  <option value='PK'>Pakistan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its quite okay but if I unselect all then option not available too

Comment: one small problem if I select all and another any option same time that another option not unselect automatically and disabled with all

Comment: How can you select all and another option at same time ?? if you selected all others will be disabled, if you selected any other 'All' will be disabled

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#device option').click(function(){
 var Allselected = $('#device :selected').text();
  var AllselectedCountry = $('#country :selected').text();
 if(Allselected =="ALL"){ 
$('#device option:not(:selected)').addClass('ashClass');
 }
 else if (Allselected !="ALL"){
$('#device option:first-child').css('color', '#ccc');
$('#device option:not(:selected)').removeClass('ashClass');
 } 
 });
  $('#country option').click(function(){
   var AllselectedCountry = $('#country :selected').text();
   if(AllselectedCountry =="ALL"){ 
$('#country option:not(:selected)').addClass('ashClass');
 }
 else if (AllselectedCountry !="ALL"){
$('#country option:first-child').css('color', '#ccc');
$('#country option:not(:selected)').removeClass('ashClass');
 
 }
 });
```

```css
.ashClass {
  color: #ccc;
}
.blackClass {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <select multiple name="device[]" id="device" class="form-control" >
                                    <option value=\'ALL\' >ALL</option><option value=\'Android\'>Android</option><option value=\'iPod\'>iPod</option><option value=\'iPad\'>iPad</option><option value=\'Java\'>Java</option><option value=\'Windows\'>Windows</option><option value=\'Linux\'>Linux</option><option value=\'Mac\'>Mac</option>                             </select>
            <select multiple name="country[]" id="country" class="form-control" >
                                    <option value=\'ALL\' >ALL</option><option value=\'BD\'>Bangladesh</option><option value=\'IN\'>India</option><option value=\'ID\'>Indonesia</option><option value=\'NG\'>Naigeria</option><option

 value=\'PK\'>Pakistan</option></select>
```

Updated the codes,Hope this one resolves your problem.
Is this what you are asking?

Comment: if I unselect all other option not available

Comment: so,instead of disabling it we can change the color to #ccc ? I think,once we disable it we cannot enable.

Comment: can u just little modify and add if unselect all other option available

Comment: Please refer to the updated above codes or use https://jsfiddle.net/Hema_Nandagopal/0xLkz301/3/

Answer (score 0):

By disabling an element you say i'll not use this element, I refuse to use this elemen, so disabled elements can not get Mouse Events, so disabling is wrong way.

Instead make it visually disabled.

Here is pure JS code, because i am not like jquery ;)

```html
<style>

select {
 height:300px;
 width:150px;
}

</style>

<body>
<select multiple name="device[]" id="device" class="form-control" onChange="Go()" >
<option value=\'ALL\' selected="selected">ALL</option>
<option value=\'Android\'>Android</option>
<option value=\'iPod\'>iPod</option>
<option value=\'iPad\'>iPad</option>
<option value=\'Java\'>Java</option>
<option value=\'Windows\'>Windows</option>
<option value=\'Linux\'>Linux</option>
<option value=\'Mac\'>Mac</option>
</select>

<select multiple name="country[]" id="device" class="form-control" onChange="Go()" >
<option value=\'ALL\' selected="selected">ALL</option>
<option value=\'BD\'>Bangladesh</option>
<option value=\'IN\'>India</option>
<option value=\'ID\'>Indonesia</option>
<option value=\'NG\'>Naigeria</option>
<option value=\'PK\'>Pakistan</option>
</select>

<script>
function Go(){
 parentElements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
 
 for(var i = 0; i < parentElements.length; i++){
  parentElement = parentElements[i]
  children = parentElement.childNodes;
  
  for(var j = 0; j < children.length; j++){
   childNode = children[j];
   
   if(childNode.nodeName == "OPTION" || childNode.nodeName == "option"){
   
    if(childNode.value == "\\'ALL\\'" && childNode.selected == true){
     
     for(var k = 0; k < children.length; k++){          
      if(typeof(children[k].value) !== "undefined" && k != j){
       children[k].style.color = "#ccc";
       children[k].style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
       children[k].selected = false;
      }
      
      if(typeof(children[k].value) !== "undefined" && k == j){
       children[k].style.color = "";
       children[k].style.textDecorationLine = "";
      }
     }
    }
    
    if(childNode.value != "\\'ALL\\'" && childNode.selected == true){
    
     for(var k = 0; k < children.length; k++){          
      if(typeof(children[k].value) !== "undefined" && children[k].value == "\\'ALL\\'"){
       children[k].style.color = "#ccc";
       children[k].style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
       children[k].selected = false;
      }
      
      if(typeof(children[k].value) !== "undefined" && children[k].value != "\\'ALL\\'"){
       children[k].style.color = "";
       children[k].style.textDecorationLine = "";
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
</body>
```